# How to use variable for device name when declaring a chain to use the (netdev) ingress hook?

Tags: nftables

For a `netdev` filter table's `ingress`  hook I'd like to store the device name in a variable, but I somehow can't figure out the correct syntax.

It works as follows:

```
table netdev filter {
    chain ingress {
        type filter hook ingress device ens33 priority -500;

        # ...
    }
}
```

... but I would like to use a variable in place of `ens33` on the line:

```
type filter hook ingress device ens33 priority -500;
```

When I use the following, I get an error:

```
define extif = ens33

table netdev filter {
    chain ingress {
        type filter hook ingress device $extif priority -500;

        # ...
    }
}
```

The error reads:

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting string or quoted string or string with a trailing asterisk
```

Now I also tried `ens*` hoping for it to be similar to `ens+` in `iptables`, but then the error changes to the one I also encounter when giving an invalid device name:

```
Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory
        chain ingress {
              ^^^^^^^
```

Similarly quoting didn't work for me. [The documentation](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Scripting) also didn't provide the clue that could make it work.

How can I place the name (or names) of my external interfaces in a variable in order to use them as parameter for `device` on the `type filter hook ...` stanza?

---

The kernel is 5.8 and the system is Ubuntu 20.04. `nftables` reports as `v0.9.3 (Topsy)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, this feature was added with [this commit](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=d100e2d811749bf34bb6aeac322052c56661c124) made available only since [nftables 0.9.7](https://lwn.net/Articles/835364/). Your ruleset works as-is when tested with nftables 0.9.8.

> [src: allow to use variables in flowtable and chain devices](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=d100e2d811749bf34bb6aeac322052c56661c124)
>
> This patch adds support for **using variables for devices in the chain**
> and flowtable definitions, eg.
>
> ```
> define if_main = lo
>
> table netdev filter1 {
>    chain Main_Ingress1 {
>        type filter hook ingress device $if_main priority -500; policy accept;
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> Signed-off-by: Pablo Neira Ayuso pablo@netfilter.org

---

A netdev family chain registers to one or [multiple](https://git.netfilter.org/nftables/commit/?id=3fdc7541fba079f9626bcb1605368a7da3a8d81a) ([since kernel 5.5 and nftables 0.9.3](https://lwn.net/Articles/806177/)) interface(s), which must all exist before the chain definition. A wildcard can't be used.

The *multidevice* chain syntax is slightly different:

```
table netdev filter {
    chain ingress {
        type filter hook ingress devices = { ens33, ens34 } priority -500;

        # ...
    }
}
```

Or with *nftables* >= 0.9.7:

```
define extifs = { ens33, ens34 }

table netdev filter {
    chain ingress {
        type filter hook ingress devices = $extifs priority -500;

        # ...
    }
}
```

Having only one interface (eg: `{ ens33 }`) is displayed back with the previous existing syntax.

Comment: While the Ubuntu equivalent of a [FrankenDebian](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian) is to consider, using only three packages from Ubuntu 21.04: libnftnl11, libnftables1, nftables on Ubuntu 20.04 provides nftables 0.9.7 and gets last example working fine in a focal container.

Comment: Actually I'd like to avoid anything like a FrankenDebian.