# What chain types are supported by the nftables NETDEV family?

Tags: firewall, netfilter, nftables

From the [nftables Quick reference](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Quick_reference-nftables_in_10_minutes):

> family refers to a one of the following table types: ip, arp, ip6,
> bridge, inet, netdev.

and

> type refers to the kind of chain to be created. Possible types are:
>
> filter: Supported by arp, bridge, ip, ip6 and inet table families.
> route: Mark packets (like mangle for the output hook, for other hooks
> use the type filter instead), supported by ip and ip6.
> nat: In order
> to perform Network Address Translation, supported by ip and ip6.

From [another document which explains how to configure chains](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_chains#Base_chain_types):

> The possible chain types are:
>
> filter, which is used to filter packets. This is supported by the arp,
> bridge, ip, ip6 and inet table families.
> route, which is used to
> reroute packets if any relevant IP header field or the packet mark is
> modified. If you are familiar with iptables, this chain type provides
> equivalent semantics to the mangle table but only for the output hook
> (for other hooks use type filter instead). This is supported by the
> ip, ip6 and inet table families.
> nat, which is used to perform
> Networking Address Translation (NAT). Only the first packet of a given
> flow hits this chain; subsequent packets bypass it. Therefore, never
> use this chain for filtering. The nat chain type is supported by the
> ip, ip6 and inet table families.

Hence, according to at least two authoritative references, no chain type is supported by the `netdev` family. Given that, how can we use the `netdev` family at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am new one, but also interested in nftables rules. I found in nftables wiki: "The principal (only?) use for this (netdev) family is for base chains using the ingress hook, new in Linux kernel 4.2." More info here, in the end of article: https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Nftables_families

Ingress hook allows you to filter L2 traffic. It comes before prerouting, after the packet is passed up from the NIC driver. This means you can enforce very early filtering policies. This very early location in the packet path is ideal for dropping packets associated with DDoS attacks.
When adding a chain on ingress hook, it is mandatory to specify the device where the chain will be attached

Source: https://www.datapacket.com/blog/securing-your-server-with-nftables

How to specify the device can be found here:
[How to use variable for device name when declaring a chain to use the (netdev) ingress hook?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647626/how-to-use-variable-for-device-name-when-declaring-a-chain-to-use-the-netdev-i/647644#647644)

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, accepted and +1. Of course, I had already found that section of the manual. However, the information in the wiki is obviously wrong which was the reason for the question.

Comment: Binarus, thank you! I just wanted to attrack attention to the question, it's very interesting for me. I didn't know that wiki is wrong. If someday you will have working example, especially in arp filtering in netdev I hope you will post it here.

Comment: There's a v5 candidate for an [egress hook](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netfilter-devel/list/?series=264397&state=*) (which will be followed by a v6 anyway). So an egress hook might appear... hopefully in kernel 5.16 or 5.17. It would allow for example to firewall a DHCP client application which currently evades nftables with raw sockets.